# Function Argument with &$

Tags: php, function, variables

I have come accross a function:

```
public function plgVmPrepareCartProduct(&$product, &$customfield,$selected,&$modificatorSum){
```

what does the & in front of the variable mean?

Comment: It means 'By Reference'. It means if you modify $product inside the function, then it will affect $product (or the original variable) outside the function too

Comment: $customfield it contains value, &$customfield contains address  of $customfield .for example:

$a=1;
$b=& $a;

echo $a ;// outputs 1
echo $b ;// also outputs 1, because it store address of $a it might be a garbage value

if you change  value of $a automatically it will affect to $b also